# MongoD doesn't stop on CentOS

Tags: mongodb, centos, backup

I try to shutdown mongoD in order to make a backup. However when I send `service mongod stop` it totally failed `Stopping mongod:[FAILED]`

I took a look on mongodb logs and there is nothing about shutdown...

I've got important data on this DB and i don't want to kill anything, so as i'm a beginner in mongoDB, I prefer to ask here what to do before destroy everything.

I was thinking about kill the process of MongoD, make my backup with mongodump and restart MongoD, but i'm not sure that it will work.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: For mongod, it should be fine just to send a SIGINT (Ctrl-C) signal and the server will shut down cleanly. You should see the evidence of the clean shutdown in the logs. Is there anything in system logs about the failure to stop the service?

Answer (score 4):

For my MongoDB 3.0 install, the problem with stopping was caused by a comment field in the /etc/mongod.conf file:

pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid # location of pidfile

This caused a problem with the awk command in /etc/init.d/mongod that defines the PIDFILEPATH since the comment text became part of the path, which then meant the mongo_killproc would not work.

I fixed this by editing the mongod.conf to move the comment to a separate line and now all is good (I did not have to change the quotes around $PIDFILEPATH either)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case it worked after editing the mongod init script. You need to remove the quotes from $PIDFILE in the stop function definition. You might need to kill the mongo process first in order for it to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I simply killed mongo process and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was "PIDFILEPATH" in the stop function and I removed the quotes

Answer (score 0):

> I think killing processes of mongodb would definitely work

```
sudo killall -15 mongod
```